# How can I map these WebApi routes in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I'm mostly using the default WebApi route mapping, as follows:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

That's working fine, and my URLs look like:

```
    [GET]  /api/customers    Get all customers
    [GET]  /api/customers/1  Get a specific customer
    [POST] /api/customers    Create a customer
```

All good so far, but now I want to add a "search" facility. For this, I'll be POSTing an object representing the search criteria, because there are too many options to do it on the URL as a GET. My plan was that the URL would look like this:

```
    [POST] /api/customers/search
```

However, with the default routing above, the server complains that "multiple actions were found that match the request", which I think is because I now have two controller methods that accept POST data (one for "create" and one for "search"), and the routing has no way to distinguish between them.

I tried adding a new route map that includes an {action} component, but that didn't resolve the problem - presumably because the URL is valid for *both* route maps. (I would somehow need to stop the "/search" variant from matching the default route map.

Suggestions please?

Comment: WHat do you mean "I'll be POSTing an object representing the search criteria"? please could you give example to POST (create new object) based on search criteria?

Comment: I mean that instead of having querystring parameters with my search terms etc., I'll be posting an object that defines the search terms in the body of my request. So the URL will simply be /api/customers/search but the request body will contain a block of XML or JSON that tells the server what words to search for, etc.

Comment: Why dont you use [POST] /api/customers?search={your search term}?

Comment: Because my URL would be too long. The search criteria include date ranges, tags, and various other options - which is why I need to POST it.

Comment: POST mean you need to create resource on web server, if you just query  and do not mofdify anything, use GET, that's principle to design REST. It also does not matter much search criteria is long in your query :)

Comment: @CuongLe: Thanks. I thought I'd read somewhere that POST could be used  other than for object creation. I'll switch to GET.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the following route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "SearchRouteName",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/search/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "customers", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Just before the DefaultApi route mapping?

Comment: This still suffers from the same problem, which is that the default route still matches the URL, and so I get the "multiple actions match" error. I don't *think* the order in which you add the route maps makes any difference (but I did try it in the order you suggested just in case).

Comment: The order in which you add the routes does make a difference as the routes are added to the collection in the order they are defined.  The routing engine will then look for matching routes UNTIL it finds one and then stops. Therefore the first route that matches your url (based on position in the list) will be selected. Could you please show your action signatures?